# How to get grub to recognize second hard drive?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

My computer has the following config:

Drive 0: SSD, windows OS

Drive 1: HDD, data storage, Ubuntu

Originally it only had windows. I partitioned off some of drive 1 and installed Ubuntu to it. However, when I boot the computer, it goes to a grub command line, because grub seems to be on drive 0, and it doesn't find drive 1. When I do "ls" in grub, it lists hd0 and the partitions on hd0, but not hd1. If I change the boot order to do windows first, it loads windows fine. If I tell UEFI to boot ubuntu directly by going into BIOS, ubuntu loads fine. But it goes back to the grub command line upon reboot.

How can I make grub find drive 1? Should I install grub on drive 1 instead? How do I do that, since I installed ubuntu on drive 1 but grub seems to be on drive 0?

Comment: With UEFI it doesn't boot drives directly, just the drive containing the ESP (EFI System Partition) and all the OS bootloaders are there. In this case it should contain entries for Windows Ubuntu and may or may not contain others from the manufacturer for recovery system, diagnostic tools, etc. If your Windows came with the PC it's in UEFI mode. Have you installed Ubuntu in the same mode? I suspect you installed in legacy/CSM/BIOS mode.

Comment: If I do 

    sudo parted -l in ubuntu,

it lists both disks. Disk 0 has an EFI system partition with a boot flag, and so does disk 1. So both seem to be in EFI mode.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Please run it fromn a live session, do NOT apply any fix at this moment. Create a BootInfo summary report only and post it here. The fix is probably simple and can be done manually.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to myself

It's not a true answer, but I have found an obvious workaround, which is to clean up my files so I had enough room to put Ubuntu and Windows on the same disk... with that it boots normally. I'm sure there is a solution to the grub thing, but this is good enough for me so I consider this matter resolved